# Adding nodes through update method

Tags: ios, swift, methods, sprite-kit

I awant to add SKSpriteNode's after something repositioned therefore I want to add the nodes through the update method in Swift Sprite Kit.

There are Objects ( platforms ) that move downwards the y axis, once they are out of screen they appear on the top side again ( like an infinite loop ). I visualize this in the update method. Note that the platforms dont really move, rather then I centered a camera on my Player node that moves up.

After the reposition of the platform node, I want to add an Enemy again on top of the platforms, however because I try it through the update method, it adds sometimes more than 1 node on top of it.

I cant reposition the Enemy like I do with the platforms, because it should be a random enemy node.

Any way to call the SpawnEnemy method in the update method, and check if it was called only once?

My Code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/* Setup your scene here */

    self.World = SKNode()
    self.World.name = "World"
    addChild(World)

    self.WorldCamera = SKNode()
    self.WorldCamera.name = "Camera"
    self.World.addChild(WorldCamera)

    ....

    SpawnPlatforms()

    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform2.position.y + 30))
    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform3.position.y + 30))
    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform4.position.y + 30))
    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform5.position.y + 30))
    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform6.position.y + 30))
    SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform7.position.y + 30))

}

func SpawnPlatforms() {


    Platform0 = SKSpriteNode (color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width * 2 , height: 25))
    Platform0.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: -36)
    Platform0.zPosition = 1

    Platform0.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:Platform0.size)
    Platform0.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Platform0.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Platform0.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    Platform0.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    Platform0.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

    Platform0.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Platform0Category
    Platform0.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PlayerCategory | EnemyCategory
    Platform0.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory | EnemyCategory

    World.addChild(Platform0)

    Platform1 = SKSpriteNode (color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width * 2 , height: 25))
    Platform1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform0.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
    Platform1.zPosition = 1

    Platform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:Platform1.size)
    Platform1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Platform1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Platform1.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Platform1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    Platform1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Platform1Category
    Platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PlayerCategory | EnemyCategory
    Platform1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory | EnemyCategory

    World.addChild(Platform1)

    ....a.s.o. for the other 6 platform nodes
}

func SpawnEnemy(position: CGPoint!){

    let random = arc4random_uniform(4)

    switch (random) {

    case 0:

        let node1 = SpawnNode1(position)

        self.addChild(node1)

        break

    case 1:

        let node2 = SpawnNode2(position)

        self.addChild(node2)

        break

    case 2:

        let node3 = SpawnNode3(position)

        self.addChild(node3)

        break

    case 3:

        break

    default:

        break
    }
}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    WorldCamera.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)

    self.centerOnNode(WorldCamera!)

}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {

    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = WorldCamera.scene!.convertPoint(WorldCamera.position, fromNode: World)

    World.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:World.position.x , y:World.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y), duration: 1.0))

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

     if(Platform1.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform7.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform1.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform1.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform2.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform1.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform2.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform2.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform3.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform3.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform2.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform3.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform3.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform4.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform4.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform3.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform4.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform4.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform5.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform5.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform4.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform5.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform5.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform6.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform6.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform5.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform6.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform6.position.y + 30))
    }

    if(Platform7.position.y < (Player.position.y - self.frame.size.height / 2)){
        Platform7.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, Platform6.position.y + self.frame.size.height / 4.5)
        Platform7.color = SKColor.redColor()
        SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: Platform7.position.y + 30))
    }

}
```

Comment: having trouble visualizing exactly whats going on here

Comment: The issue I stated or my code?

Comment: platformrespawn is confusing.. and your issue is confusing

Comment: The platforms, that are already added, move along the y-axis down. Platformrespawn just defines, if the platform is out of the screen (bottom), it appears on top of the screen again. The problem is, within the PlatformRespawn, I need to call the SpawnEnemy method again, but if I call it in the update method, it adds about 40 Enemy Nodes, instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you do not create any kind of check that moving the platform has already spawned an enemy.  Sure, you move the platform, but until your player moves, it will constantly spawn enemies.  I do not see where this is happening, but you should spawn enemy when you move the platform, not on your update

Edit:
yikes,  I see it now,  this is some ugly code lol,  In all those ifs that move the platform, you should spawn the enemy.  But this needs to be  worked to also check if the previous platform is below the current, not above

Edit++:
Upon further review and added details, try something like this instead:

First, give all Platforms a name "Platform"

Then

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    for node in scene.children
    {
        if (node.name == "Platform" && !node.intersectsNode(scene) && node.position.y  < player.y - (self.frame.size.height / 4.5))
        {
            let platform = node as! SKSpriteNode
            platform.position.y += (7  * (self.frame.size.height / 4.5))
            platform.color = SKColor.redColor()
            SpawnEnemy(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: platform.position.y + 30))

        }
    }
}
```

Question: How does this even work,  I would just check if a platform hits a certain point in the scene, recycle it, instead of having to check every single platform and moving it's previous one

Comment: I also thought of that, but the problem is I dont "really" move the platforms, I rather have a camera node that keeps focusing on the player, and while the player "jumps" the camera moves with the player. Therefore I need to reposition the platforms in the update method.

Comment: if you are using the camera, then couldn't you just use `if(!platform.intersectsNode(cameranode) and platform.y < player.y)`

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont seem to understand what sense the code would make.
I added my camera in the code.

Comment: your camera is an SKCameraNode,  you want to check when the platform is not in the view of the camera,  if the platform is not in the view of the camera, and below the player, move the platform

Comment: @Albert,  nevermind, you are not using a real camera, you are using a fake camera that makes no sense, and is not even needed,  so the scene is always centered on the player.  instead of camera node use the scene, `if(!platform.intersectsNode(scene)  and platform.y < player.y) `

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Yes I am setting the center of the scene on the player, thats what the camera node is for.
Unfortunately, the code doesn't work.
Here is the game mechanic I strive for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8zsszg5n2A

Comment: @Albert you do not need the camera node do `self.centerOnNode(player)`.  What doesn't work?

Comment: Firstly I cant call the method .color to a SKNode, and then also actually nothing happens If I use the code. What exactly does bother you with the `self.centerOnNode(player)`, because I actually only followed the official Apple document for setting a SKCameraNode.

Comment: @Albert, you don't use skcameranode though, you use sknode, right now your camera  is a waste and adds more complexity than needed.  I updated my post for your color problem

Comment: if nothing happens, that means you didn't give your platforms the name "Platform"

Comment: if you want the platform to disappear even on screen, just take out the intersect check all together,  my math basically just says move any platform below the player that the player is not standing on and is off screen to the top

Answer (score 0):

so you're spawning an enemy on every frame.. thats going to be way too many enemies..  I'm still not totally following the exact architecture of your game, but this might help you out.

get delta time to see how much time has passed.. and every 10 seconds (or whatever) call your spawn enemy code instead of calling it on every frame

```
// time values
var delta = NSTimeInterval(0)
var last_update_time = NSTimeInterval(0)

let spawnTimerMax = NSTimeInterval(10)
var spawnTimer = NSTimeInterval(0)

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if last_update_time == 0.0 {
        delta = 0
    } else {
        delta = currentTime - last_update_time
    }

    last_update_time = currentTime

    // ten seconds elapsed, spawn enemy and restart.
    spawnTimer += delta
    if spawnTimer >= spawnTimerMax {
        // your spawn code goes here
        spawnTimer = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: so youre trying to spawn an enemy on your new platform when it comes into view?

Comment: I edited my code now for better visualization, also I dont really add a new platform node, I just change the position of it in the update method. Every time the position changes from the bottom to the top, the Enemy node that was on top of the platform is gone, so I need to call the method again to add an Enemy.